# Meteor + Mongo (2.6.7) Pushing Document to Array in Sorted Order

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document with an array (which should be denormalised, but can't be because the reactive events will fire "add" too many times at client startup).

I need to be able to push a document to that array, and keep it in sorted (or roughly sorted) order. I've tried this query:

```
{ $push: {
   'events': {
       $each: [{'id': new Mongo.ObjectID, 'start':startDate,...}],
       $sort: {'start': 1},
       $slice: -1
    }
}
```

But it requires the `$slice` operator to be present... I don't want to delete all my old data, I just want to be able to insert data into an array, and then have that array be sorted so that I can query the array later and say "slice greater than or equal to time X".

Is this possible?

Edit:

This mongo aggregate query nearly works, except for one level of document in the result array, but aggregating is not reactive (probably because they're expensive computations). Here is the aggregate query if anyone can see how to translate it to a find, or why it can't be translated:

```
Coll.aggregate({$unwind: '$events'},
     {$sort: {'events.start':1}},
     {$match: {'events.start': {$gte: new Date()}}},
     {$group: {_id: '$_id', 'events': {$push: '$events'} }})
```

Comment: MongoDB 2.6.x does not require the `$slice` operator, it's just optional. It would be required with an earlier release like 2.4.x. At any rate, just use `"$slice": 99999` or whatever number is reasonable enough to be larger than the expected entries in the array so it does not actually cut anything off.

Comment: Why don't you show what you attempted with the denormalized approach, which you say didn't work due to reactive updates firing too often?

Comment: I'm sure denormalizing 'works' in the sense that I can think of the query, but the fact of the matter is full calendar can't handle a billion render events at load time because of the number of denormalized documents. The answer to this question, however is to store them in 'roughly' sorted order, then use a mongo aggregate at publication time. I'm working on the query now and will post it if I get it

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I have more problems than I know what to deal with, a somewhat related question is this (but it is centered on something different so I made it a separate question) but I actually get a minimongo error using mongo 2.6.7 (server side method). Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748426/minimongo-error-on-serverside-meteor-script.

Comment: Minimongo and MongoDB server API support are two different things. For mnimongo the syntax is different. Call this as a meteor method instead with server side code only and implement the call there. minimongo support just is not on par with what the server methods can do.

Comment: Weirdest thing is -- I am calling it from a file in `/server` what I've done is just do the slice thing and made a note in the codebase. Slice is really good enough for the 'rapid prototyping' aspect of meteor. But production security and API regularity... I don't know yet.